# Sorting single CSV to many CSV's

Tags: vb.net, parsing, csv

I have a master CSV file that looks sorta like this

```
Area Code,City,Phone
123,somecity,somenumber
123,somecity,somenumber
321,somecity,somenumber
918,somecity,somenumber
```

so on and so forth.

I would like to create seperate CSVs for each area code.
So a 123.csv file would only contain records where the area code is = 123. 
The 321.csv file would only contain records where the area code is = 321.

I understand how to create CSV files, and how to parse them. 
What I dont understand is this -- How can I parse for just area code. -AND- How do I then select the data from only that row to place into it's particular csv file.

This is a VB.Net project,
Thanks :)

--As a side note I should mention I am currently grabbing this information from SQL, then converting it to a string, then to a csv file. I have that conversion done, but I'm not sure if it would be easier to parse as a string, or as a csv file.

Comment: If you are getting the information from SQL, skip the main csv and generate the area-code specific csv directly from the data.

Comment: If you get the data from a database, why not create the proper CSV files in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do is:

1. Read all the lines into memory using `File.ReadAllLines`
2. Add these lines to a dictionary based on the the area code
3. Loop over the dictionary and write each line to a file named after the area code using `File.AppendText`.

I'm not a VB guy, but the following C# code might help you still:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFileName);
Dictionary<string, List<string>> linesByAreaCode = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // Two parts, one for the area code, one for the rest
    string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 2); 

    // Add a new list for the lines for an area code if it doesn't exist
    if (!linesByAreaCode.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
        linesByAreaCode[parts[0]] = new List<string>();

    // Add the line to the list of lines for the area code
    linesByAreaCode[parts[0]].Add(line);
}

foreach (string key in linesByAreaCode.Keys)
{
    List<string> lines = linesByAreaCode[key];
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // Write this line to the file [key].csv
    }
}
```

---

Given your edit to the question, it would be far easier to generate the required CSV files directly from the database information instead of first creating a string, writing that to one CSV just to split that.

Comment: Yes, thank you. After looking into it, I believe it would be a lot easier to just go straight from the sql data to individual files. The data is stored in a datatable which is far easier to process than a csv. I think I got ahead of myself while writing today. Must be a monday ;) thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Why not parse everything (using "," as a delimiter) and then sort out the 3 digit area codes from everything else? This is assuming no one has a 3 digit phone number, otherwise this should work. Just from a quick Google search, it looks like the following code can select 3 digit numbers:

```
If IsNumeric(Range("A1")) And Len(Range("A1")) = 3 Then
'...
End If
```

Then, to put them in different CSV files, I'd just create an array for each area code and sort them into those, then loop through those arrays and put them into separate CSVs through those.

Obviously, above is more of a template than actual code to use, but I hope this is of some use.